# In Scala, is there a way to get the currently evaluated items in a Stream?

Tags: scala, stream, lazy-evaluation

In Scala, is there a way to get the currently evaluated items in a Stream? For example in the Stream

```
val s: Stream[Int] = Stream.cons(1, Stream.cons(2, Stream.cons(3, s.map(_+1))))
```

the method should return only `List(1,2,3)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In 2.8, there is a protected method called `tailDefined` that will return false when you get to the point in the stream that has not yet been evaluated.

This isn't too useful (unless you want to write your own `Stream` class) except that `Cons` itself makes the method public.  I'm not sure why it's protected in Stream and not in Cons--I would think one or the other might be a bug.  But for now, at least, you can write a method like so (writing a functional equivalent is left as an exercise to the reader):

```
def streamEvalLen[T](s: Stream[T]) = {
  if (s.isEmpty) 0
  else {
    var i = 1
    var t = s
    while (t match {
      case c: Stream.Cons[_] => c.tailDefined
      case _ => false
    }) {
      i += 1
      t = t.tail
    }
    i
  }
}
```

Here you can see it in action:

```
scala> val s = Stream.iterate(0)(_+1)
s: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(0, ?)

scala> streamEvalLen(s)
res0: Int = 1

scala> s.take(3).toList
res1: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2)

scala> s
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(0, 1, 2, ?)

scala> streamEvalLen(s)
res3: Int = 3
```

Comment: The method `tailDefined` is public in both `Cons` and `Empty` so I don't think it is a bug. I didn't notice that earlier. I can adapt your solution to solve my problem.

Answer (score 6):

The solution based on [Rex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831989/in-scala-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-currently-evaluated-items-in-a-stream/2835532#2835532):

```
def evaluatedItems[T](stream: => Stream[T]): List[T] = {
  @tailrec
  def inner(s: => Stream[T], acc: List[T]): List[T] = s match {
    case Empty => acc
    case c: Cons[T] => if (c.tailDefined) {
      inner(c.tail, acc ++ List(c.head))
    } else { acc ++ List(c.head) }
  }
  inner(stream, List())
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Type that statement into the interactive shell and you will see that it evaluates to `s: Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)`. So, in fact, the other two elements of 2 and 3 are not yet known.

As you access further elements, more of the stream is calculated. So, now put `s(3)` into the shell, which will return `res0: Int = 2`. Now put `s` into the shell and you will see the new value `res1: Stream[Int] = Stream(1, 2, 3, 2, ?)`.

The only method I could find that contained the information that you wanted was, unfortunately, `s.toString`. With some parsing you will be able to get the elements back out of the string. This is a barely acceptable solution with just ints and I couldn't imagine any generic solution using the string parsing idea.

Answer (score 0):

Using scanLeft

```
    lazy val s: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: s.scanLeft(2) { case (a, _) => 1 + a }
```